# Help with creating the NetChain

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to train a network to take 3 integers and give an output = Max/Min. For example {10, 20, 30} -> 3. But I cannot get the setup correctly. I must be missing something.

```
x = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 
    RandomInteger[{1, 100}]}, 1000];
y = (Max[#]/Min[#] // N) & /@ x;
t = x -> y // Thread;
net = NetChain[{LongShortTermMemoryLayer[10], 
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[10], LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> {3, 1}, 
  "Output" -> 1]
p = NetTrain[net, t, ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]]
```

I get the following error:
*NetTrain*: Data provided to port "Input" should be a non-empty list of 3x1 matrices of real numbers, but was a 1000x3 matrix of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Partition[#, 1] & /@Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}],RandomInteger[{1, 100}]}, 1000]; 
y = Partition[((Max[#]/Min[#] // N) & /@ x), 1];
t = x -> y // Thread;

net = NetChain[{LongShortTermMemoryLayer[10], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[10], LinearLayer[1]}, "Input" -> {3, 1}, "Output" -> 1]

p = NetTrain[net, t, ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]];
NetMeasurements[p, t, "MeanSquare"]

ListPlot[Transpose[{Flatten[p /@ x], Flatten[y]}]]
```